# Matlab - finding nearest neighbor in three-dimensional coordinate system

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, nearest-neighbor

Welcome!

I have a set of **n** matlab matrix with the following structure:

```
xyz_1   -3,37200000000000   2,80000000000000    5,03400000000000

xyz_2   -2,21700000000000   1,74500000000000    7,45300000000000

....    ..................  ................    ................

xyz_n  -1,39300000000000    0,00700000000000000 6,35500000000000
```

where the first column is the **name of matrix**, while the next three columns are the **xyz coordinates**. I' am looking for an efficient way to find the nearest neighbor. I would like to give the matrix name and **k** of potential neighbors as the input parameter then program will find the nearest neighbors giving me the result matrix in the following form:

```
[nearest_neighbor_name_1;    distance_between_quoted_element_and_nearest_neigbor_1

 nearest_neighbor_name_2;    distance_between_quoted_element_and_nearest_neigbor_2

 nearest_neighbor_name_....; distance_between_quoted_element_and_nearest_neigbor_....

 nearest_neighbor_name_k;    distance_between_quoted_element_and_nearest_neigbor_k]
```

I tried to use the  `knnsearch`unfortunately without effect. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please reformat the question using \` for code segments. Also: What do you mean by: *I tried to use `knnsearch` without effect*? Why was this approach unsatisfactory?

Comment: I found the description how to searching two dimensional coordinates. Unfortunately I have no idea how to use the `knnseach` in the case of a three-dimensional system. In addition, the input parameter for `knneseach` are single matrices (X and Y)  not, as in my case, a set of multi-array.

Comment: Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475978/finding-k-nearest-neighbour-with-matlab/27476929#27476929) for insight.  Make sure you format your data such that each row is a point and each column is a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the traditional way of unsatisfactory in some way?  Evaluate the distance from each point to your test point and then sort the distances...

```
%define the "k" entries that you are interested in assessing
mydata_xyz = [-3.37200000000000   2.80000000000000    5.03400000000000;
              -2.21700000000000   1.74500000000000    7.45300000000000;
                        <the rest of your data here>
              -1.39300000000000    0.00700000000000000 6.35500000000000];

%define the point about which you are looking for the nearest neighbors
mypoint_xyz = [ <whatever your xyz coordinate is];


%compute the distance from the given point to all of the other test points.
%Note the use of the transpose (apostrophe) to ensure that it sums in the
% correct direction
distance = sqrt(sum( ((mydata_xyz - ones(size(mydata_xyz,1),1)*mypoint_xyz).^2)' )); 

%sort to get the nearest neighbor followed by the next nearest neighbors
[sorted_distance, Isort] = sort(distance);

%print out each one of the points, from closest to farthest
for I=1:length(Isort)
    disp(['Point ' num2str(Isort) ...
          ', dist = ' num2str(distance(Isort(I))) ...
          ', xyz = ' num2str(mydata_xyz(Isort(I),:))]);
end
```