# Matlab calculating nearest neighbour distance for all (u, v) vectors in an array

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vector, distance

I am trying to calculate the distance between nearest neighbours within a nx2 matrix like the one shown below

```
point_coordinates =

   11.4179  103.1400
   16.7710   10.6691
   16.6068  119.7024
   25.1379   74.3382
   30.3651   23.2635
   31.7231  105.9109
   31.8653   36.9388





%for loop going from the top of the vector column to the bottom
for counter = 1:size(point_coordinates,1) 
    %current point defined selected 
    current_point = point_coordinates(counter,:);

    %math to calculate distance between the current point and all the points 
    distance_search= point_coordinates-repmat(current_point,[size(point_coordinates,1) 1]);
    dist_from_current_point = sqrt(distance_search(:,1).^2+distance_search(:,2).^2);

    %line to omit self subtraction that gives zero
    dist_from_current_point (dist_from_current_point <= 0)=[];

    %gives the shortest distance calculated for a certain vector and current_point
    nearest_dist=min(dist_from_current_point);

end

%final line to plot the u,v vectors and the corresponding nearest neighbour
%distances
matnndist = [point_coordinates nearest_dist]
```

I am not sure how to structure the 'for' loop/nearest_neighbour line to be able to get the nearest neighbour distance for each u,v vector.

I would like to have, for example ;
for the first vector you could have the coordinates and the corresponding shortest distance, for the second vector another its shortest distance, and this goes on till n

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I can suggest a built-in function, use [`knnsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) from the statistics toolbox.  What you are essentially doing is a [K-Nearest Neighbour (KNN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) algorithm, but you are ignoring self-distances.  The way you would call `knnsearch` is in the following way:

```
[idx,d] = knnsearch(X, Y, 'k', k);
```

In simple terms, the KNN algorithm returns the `k` **closest** points to your data set given a query point.  Usually, the Euclidean distance is the distance metric that is used.  For MATLAB's `knnsearch`, `X` is a 2D array that consists of your dataset where each **row** is an observation and each **column** is a variable.  `Y` would be the query points.  `Y` is also a 2D array where each **row** is a query point and you need to have the same number of columns as `X`.  We would also specify the flag `'k'` to denote how many closest points you want returned.  By default, `k = 1`.

As such, `idx` would be a `N x K` matrix, where `N` is the total number of query points (number of rows of `Y`) and `K` would be those `k` closest points to the dataset for each query point we have.  `idx` indicates the particular points in your dataset that were closest to each query.  `d` is also a `N x K` matrix that returns the smallest **distances** for these corresponding closest points.

As such, what you want to do is find the closest point for your dataset to each of the other points, ignoring self-distances.  Therefore, you would set both `X` and `Y` to be the same, and set `k = 2`, discarding the first column of both outputs to get the result you're looking for.

Therefore:

```
[idx,d] = knnsearch(point_coordinates, point_coordinates, 'k', 2)
idx = idx(:,2);
d = d(:,2);
```

We thus get for `idx` and `d`:

```
>> idx

idx =

     3
     5
     1
     1
     7
     3
     5

>> d

d =

   17.3562
   18.5316
   17.3562
   31.9027
   13.7573
   20.4624
   13.7573
```

---

As such, this tells us that for the first point in your data set, it matched with point #3 the best.  This matched with the closest distance of 17.3562. For the second point in your data set, it matched with point #5 the best with the closest distance being 18.5316.  You can continue on with the rest of the results in a similar pattern.

---

If you don't have access to the statistics toolbox, consider reading my StackOverflow post on how I compute KNN from first principles.

[Finding K-nearest neighbors and its implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475978/finding-k-nearest-neighbour-with-matlab/27476929#27476929)

In fact, it is very similar to [Luis Mendo's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28099168/3250829) to you earlier.

---

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

I understand you want to obtain *the minimum distance between different points*.

You can compute the distance for each pair of points with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html); remove self-distances; minimize. It's more computationally efficient to work with squared distances, and take the square root only at the end.

```
n = size(point_coordinates,1);
dist = bsxfun(@minus, point_coordinates(:,1), point_coordinates(:,1).').^2 + ...
       bsxfun(@minus, point_coordinates(:,2), point_coordinates(:,2).').^2;
dist(1:n+1:end) = inf; %// remove self-distances
min_dist = sqrt(min(dist(:)));
```

Alternatively, you could use [`pdist`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html). This avoids computing each distance twice, and also avoids self-distances:

```
dist = pdist(point_coordinates);
min_dist = min(dist(:));
```