# How to improve the distance calculation on two separated datasets in matlab?

Tags: matlab, distance

How to improve the distance calculation on the 2 separated datasets?

This is the code:

```
X = [   3.6     79
        1.8     54
        3.333   74
        2.283   62
        4.533   85
        2.883   55
        4.7     88
        3.6     85
        1.95    51
        4.35    85
        1.833   54
        3.917   84
        4.2     78
        1.75    47
        4.7     83
        2.167   52
        1.75    62
        4.8     84
        1.6     52
        4.25    79
        1.8     51
        1.75    47
        3.45    78
        3.067   69
        4.533   74
        3.6     83
        1.967   55
        4.083   76
        3.85    78
        4.433   79
        4.3     73
        4.467   77
        3.367   66
        4.033   80
        3.833   74
        2.017   52
        1.867   48
        4.833   80
        1.833   59
        4.783   90  ]
    clc;  
    close all; 
    figure;
    h(1) = plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'bx');
    hold on;
    X1 = X(1:3,:);
    X2 = X(4:40,:);
    h(2) = plot(X1(1:3,1), X1(1:3,2),'rs','MarkerSize',10);
    k=5;
    [D2 ind] = sort(squeeze(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,X2,permute(X1,[3 2 1])).^2,2))))
    ind_closest = ind(1:k,:)
    x_closest = X(ind_closest,:)
    for j = 1:length(x_closest);
        h(3) =plot(x_closest(j,1),x_closest(j,2),'ko','MarkerSize',10);
    end
```

The output is shown as in the picture below:
[image]

The problem is, the code does not pick the closest data points of red squared data points. I also tried to use pdist2 function from statistical toolbox,the result yields similar with  the bsxfun function that i applied in my code.
I'm not sure which part in the code need to improve so that i can pick the data points that closest to the target.
Really appreciate if anyone can help me to improve my code

Comment: We need your dataset, because your code, as is, is not reproductible.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo the csv file is available in here : https://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/rdataset/source/tree/master/csv/datasets/faithful.csv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding K-nearest neighbors and its implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475978/finding-k-nearest-neighbors-and-its-implementation)

Comment: @Hunter Jiang, thank you very much for the url. I have tried and it is work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

- If the `closest point` means closest to `X`, line 19 & line 20 should be replaced as

  [D2 ind] = sort(squeeze(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,**X**,permute(X1,[3 2 1])).^2,2))))

  ind_closest = ind(**2:k+1**,:)
- If the `closest point` means closest to `X2`, then try this:

  x_closest = **X2**(ind_closest,:)

In the meanwhile, I modified your code a little bit, since your `h(3)` could be optimized.

```
clc; clear; close all;         
%load fisheriris 
%X=meas(:,3:4);
load X
X=unique(X,'rows');

figure;
h(1) = plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'bx');
hold on;

X1 = X([5 15 30],:);
h(2) = plot(X1(:,1), X1(:,2),'rs','MarkerSize',10);
[D2,ind] = sort(squeeze(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,X,permute(X1,[3 2 1])).^2,2))));

k=3;
ind_closest = unique(ind(2:k+1,:));
x_closest = X(ind_closest,:);
h(3) =plot(x_closest(:,1),x_closest(:,2),'ko','MarkerSize',10);
axis equal
```

It seems to be working fine.

[image]

Comment: @amjay I've tried your data. Note that your `csv` file has 3 columns so use `X = faithfuldat(1:40,2:3);` instead.

Comment: i just updated my recent data. I had tried to implement your suggestion, it is improve little bit, but does not pick the closest data points as shown in this page:  https://www.codementor.io/tips/9712834528/finding-k-nearest-neighbour-with-matlab

Comment: It seems to work. What's wrong? I updated my post and please point it out.

Comment: Adding an `axis equal` at the end, maybe you could find the answer is right.