# How to write code the Chebyshev and Mahalanobis distance using bsxfun function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, distance, bsxfun, mahalanobis

I found the sample code to calculate distance of two matrix using euclidean distance from here: [Finding K-nearest neighbors and its implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475978/finding-k-nearest-neighbors-and-its-implementation) The data matrix are as below:

```
load fisheriris 
X = meas(:,3:4);
newpoints = [5 1.45; 7 2; 4 2.5; 2 3.5];
```

How i'm going to apply the Chebyshev and Mahalanobis distance and replace the function below:

```
%// Use Euclidean
dists = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, x, newpoint).^2, 2));
```

I tried to change the code as :

```
dists = max(abs(bsxfun(@minus, X, newpoint)))
```

The answer is as below. May be because i put the max function based on the formula.

```
dists2 =
      4.0000    1.3500
```

But, if i used this knnsearch code, it is work as expected. But i need to apply the bsxfun so that my code will be standardized with the upper codes. I want to compare the different distances in my algorithm:

```
[ncb,dcb] = knnsearch(X,newpoint,'k',10,'distance','chebychev')
```

Appreciate if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the extented version of my answer here:

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/386963-how-to-write-code-the-chebyshev-and-mahalanobis-distance-using-bsxfun-function

the quintessence:

```
load fisheriris 
oldpoints = meas(:,3:4);
newpoints = [5 1.45; 7 2; 4 2.5; 2 3.5];
newpoints = permute(newpoints, [3,2,1]);
% Euclidean distance
dists_euclid = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, newpoints, oldpoints).^2, 2));
% Chebyshev distance
dists_cheby = max(abs(bsxfun(@minus, oldpoints, newpoints)),[],2);
```